# Using Spark DataFrame and Window Functions to calculate the rolling average return

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

It's my first time working with spark data frames and I am trying to figure out how to use the window functions to compute the average daily return of every stock for every date.

I am trying to group by the ticker and then try to apply a rolling difference window function, but I can't find a lot of documentation on the window functions or how they work.

The data I have is date, open price, high price, low price, close price, volume traded, and ticker.

You find rolling average return by subtracting the close price yesterday from the close price today and then dividing it all by the close price yesterday.

What I tried so far:

w = Window()
df.groupBy("ticker")

I am trying to learn how to use window and groupby together to solve my problem.

Comment: which fields do you use to calculate average returns?

Comment: @vdep added formula above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
w = Window().partitionBy("ticker").orderBy("date")

df.withColumn("percentDiff", (col("close") - lag("close", 1).over(w)) / lag("close", 1).over(w)) \
  .groupBy("date").agg(mean("percentDiff"))
```

Comment: How can I see the windows separately? Like the percent diff for each ticker?

Comment: The reason why I ask is because I want to get the std dev for each ticker too.

Comment: Add another aggregation for that?

Comment: df.agg(stddev("avg(daily_return)")).show() I tried this, but it only displays one number. I want to see it for every ticker/window.